# Categorize inbox items and create a separate page for viewing messages

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox

I think the message system in Stack Exchange sites is from the 90's. There are no groups/categories in the inbox. If it would categorize, it will be a great help for those who are searching old messages of a particular Stack Exchange site.

So I'm just requesting a new feature for it.

Comment: If you just want more space than there is available in the inbox to look at your notifications, you can use the [network inbox](http://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the inbox is okay the way it is. The inbox just shows the items sorted on date, and that is the way I usually prefer it.

If you want to dig deeper, or want to filter on the inbox items, you can use your profile page which contains [a responses tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/me?tab=responses). You can filter and (manually) search there.

Answer (score 1):

The reputation notification has a small part where the rep for the day for the individual site is displayed. This is because a user might accumulate several rep for a single day, and thus that feature makes sense.

However, it is very rare that a user has a lot of comments in his inbox. In fact, I don't have more than 10 inbox messages at a time, and for high-rep/active users, it must be around 25 or so.

And those can be easily sifted through. **So, making a feature which doesn't really add a significant utility doesn't really make sense and is not advised.**

And, as lot of users prefer the inbox feature as is (agreeing with Patrick here). So, maybe it isn't worth spending developer time on.